# What is the maximum storable float value with 9 decimal places?

Tags: floating-point

I was wondering after what max value would float overflow given a requirement of 9 decimal places

Comment: How big is your 'float'? The *standard* IEEE 754 float is 4 bytes and "is a binary format that occupies 32 bits (4 bytes) and its significand has a precision of 24 bits (about 7 decimal digits)." [wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Floating_point). You need at least a "double float" then. (Edit) And the answer to your question is "at MAX_FLOAT, of course". Every (double) float up to MAX_FLOAT has exactly the same number of decimal places.

Comment: @Jongware While I find the question extremely imprecise and the use of “overflow” clearly at odds with the conventional meaning of the word, I am pretty sure that in English, “decimal places” refers to digits to the right of a decimal point. No float above 8388608 has any of these, so clearly not all floats have the same number of them.

Comment: +1. That indeed sounds like a better interpretation. I was thinking of the number of decimals *without* any specific value for the exponent -- that's my "the same for every float value".

Comment: @PascalCuoq: Why would anybody care about the number of decimal places to represent the float? It is more likely the requirement is the floating-point values be able to distinguish all numbers (in range) with nine decimal places.

Comment: @EricPostpischil I still don't know what this question means, even with your comment. As for the “Why would anybody care…” part, I would have imagined that nobody would care what `++i + i++` evaluates to, yet it is asked twice daily. People ask the strangest things.

Comment: One way to interpret this question is by assuming we are talking about a decimal floating-point format. Then, the title of the question does not contradict its body and Eric's answer is spot on. Under this assumption my answer is spot on too: the notion of decimal places in the exact value of a float coincides with the usable decimal places that can be set by the user. So, a word of warning for the OP: neither `0.000000001` nor `0.000000002` are represented exactly as float or as doubles. If you represent `8388607.999999993` as a double, you are getting it wrong by nearly `0.00000000045`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

8,388,608, for IEEE-754 64-bit binary floating-point, often known as `double`.

For all values below this magnitude, the step size between adjacent representable values is less than 10<sup>-9</sup>, so each number representable with nine decimal digits after the decimal point can be distinguished from others.

Above that magnitude, the step size is too large. The next larger representable value is 8,388,608.00000000186264514923095703125, which we see is closer to 8,388,608.000000002 than to 8,388,608.000000001, so we would not have any floating-point value that distinguishes 8,388,608.000000001 from 8,388,608.000000002 and from 8,388,608.

For 32-bit, the largest value would be .015625. So 32-bit `float` is probably not useful.

Answer (score 0):

The float `32767.998046875` has 9 decimal places and no float above it needs 9 decimal places to be represented. Its successors are 32768.0 and then 32768.00390625. For these numbers and all floats above them, all fractional parts are multiples of `0.00390625` and require 8 decimal places or less to be represented exactly.

Or perhaps your question is about something else. Between 16384 and 32768, some floats have 9 decimal places, like `32767.998046875`, but you cannot choose the digits you want (for instance `32767.998055555` is not representable as a float). Perhaps you are thinking of 9 decimal places of your choice, instead of the format's choice. In this case the answer is simpler: no float allows you to pick 9 arbitrary significant decimal digits and guarantee that you will get these same digits back. The float format only allows you to get back 6 decimal digits.